# addEventListener is not working on js generated elements (images)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm placing a bunch of images on a grid in the center of the page and want to add a check for when each individual image is clicked. The images are created with js and added to the document, could it be an issue of them not being 'ready' yet or something?

```js
function placePieces() {
  for (var i = 0; i < setup.length; i++) {
    if ((setup[i]+'' == "undefined")) {continue;}
    var element = document.createElement("img");
    element.src = "Images/" + pieces[Object.keys(pieces)[setup[i]]] + ".png";
    element.style.width = "10vh";
    element.style.height = "10vh";
    element.style.marginTop = (Math.floor(i/8) * 10) + "vh";
    element.style.marginLeft = "calc(((100vw - 80vh)/2) + " + (10 * (i%8) - 1) + "vh)";
    element.style.zIndex = 10;
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    element.id = i+1;
    document.body.innerHTML = "\n" + element.outerHTML + document.body.innerHTML;
    console.log(element.outerHTML)
    var nelement = document.getElementById(i+1);
    console.log(nelement)
    nelement.addEventListener("click",highlight);
  }
}
placePieces()

function highlight(n) {
  console.log(n)
  n = n.currentTarget.myParam;
  if (setup[n] == 0 || setup[n] == 6) {
    var moves = [];
    var m = n
    while (True) {
      if (!(Math.floor((m-9)/8)<=0)) {
        console.log("test")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second function is far from finished but it still does not return anything when it should.

Comment: `element.id = i+1`: I don't think HTML5 supports ids with numeric values. You might be getting null from `addEventListener` because HTML didn't accept the id.

Comment: Try making an id like `element.id = "element" + (i + 1)`

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: Try running `document.querySelector("#0")` and see if you get an error

Comment: There was no error when adapting it to the new id format.

Comment: this is very strange. I don't see any problems with what you're doing, I don't know why it's not working. If you inspect element can you see any attached events to the element? Any other errors on the page?

Comment: I do not see any attached events upon inspection, and there are no errors being reported.

Comment: Ok, so the events are not being added. Try putting all of the code in `window.addEventListener("load", () => { [[CODE GOES HERE]] });`, so it executes after the window is loading (after everything is rendered and added on the page)

Comment: That code worked, it successfully called move(). I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: What does your html look like? Can you elaborate on "not working"? Is there an error? Does it do nothing?

Comment: NEVER use createElement and innerHTML to add it. You have append, appendChild, and insertBefore. When you use innerHTML it will wipe away all the event listeners you add.

Comment: @epascarello thanks! that makes a lot of sense, I wasn't aware of insertBefore being used with the body.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to grab the element again, you can add the listener directly

```js
const element = document.createElement('div')
element.style.background = 'red'
element.style.width = '100px'
element.style.height = '100px'
element.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'))
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

This should work:

```
function placePieces() {
  for (var i = 0; i < setup.length; i++) {
    if ((setup[i]+'' == "undefined")) {continue;}
    var element = document.createElement("img");
    // ...
    element.addEventListener("click",highlight);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution will only work if they do not use innerHTML to add the element

Comment: @epascarello wow, I didn't see that. I didn't even know you could do that. Why would anyone want to use `innerHTML` after creating the element?

Answer (score 1):

### [Event Handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers)

You have two choices:

|  | Method | Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Bind (or register) the "click" event to each `<img>`. | Easier to write | Any dynamically added `<img>` must be registered to "click" event. |
| B | Bind the "click" event to an ancestor tag in which all `<img>`'s reside within. Write the event handler so that it only reacts when an `<img>` is clicked. This paradigm is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) | Only needs to register to the event to only one tag once and any dynamically added `<img>` do not need any binding | Writing the event handler is harder. |

When reviewing the example:

1. Click some `<img>` in Area A and B. There should be a blue outline.
2. Next, click both <kbd>ADD</kbd> buttons.
3. Click some of the new `<img>`s. The new `<img>` in Area A do not work.
4. Click the <kbd>BIND</kbd> button.
5. Click any of the new `<img>` in Area A

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// File names of all images
const images = ["Fqsw6v8/2s", "Qb6N0dG/3s", "qnGtC68/4s", "nDFmjJB/5s", "sPtNDGm/6s", "HpmggvF/7s", "dKfcwxQ/8s", "K7HbrWp/9s", "9ys8PXt/as", "HVK2zvw/bs", "7SgXHz2/cs", "StdB11X/ds", "cN9CnV5/es"];
// File names of the first 3 images which will be added to DOM at page load
const init = [images[0], images[1], images[2]];

/**
 * Generate one or more <img>s from a given array/
 * @param {Array} array - An array of file names
 * @param {String|Object} node - Either a selector string or a DOM object referenced to
 *        be the elemment to append the <img>s to.
 * @param {String} css - A className to be assigned to each <img> @default
 *        is "img"
 * @returns {array} - An array of <img>
 */
function genImg(array, node, css = "img") {
  let root = typeof node === "string" ? 
    document.querySelector(node) : node ? 
    node : document.body;
  let offset = root.childElementCount;
  const pix = array.flatMap((img, idx) => {
    if (idx >= offset) { 
      const image = new Image();
      const frame = document.createElement("figure");
      image.src = `https://i.ibb.co/${img}.png`;
      image.className = css;
      image.dataset.idx = offset + idx;
      root.append(frame.appendChild(image));
      return image;
    } 
    return [];
  });
  return pix;
}

const main = document.forms.gallery;
const io = main.elements;
const areas = Array.from(io.area);

const imgsA = genImg(init, areas[0]);
const imgsB = genImg(init, areas[1]);

imgsA.forEach(img => img.onclick = highlightA);

function highlightA(event) {
  this.classList.toggle("highlight");
}

areas[1].onclick = highlightB;

function highlightB(event) {
  const clk = event.target;
  if (clk.matches("img")) {
    clk.classList.toggle("highlight");
  }
}

const btns = Array.from(io.add);
btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = addImg);

function addImg(event) {
  const clk = event.target;
  if (clk.matches("button")) {
    let idx = btns.indexOf(clk);
    genImg(images, areas[idx]);
  }
}

const bind = io.bind;
bind.onclick = bindImg;

function bindImg(event) {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#A img"))
  .forEach(img => img.onclick = highlightA);
}
```

```css
html {font: 300 4vmin/1.15 "Segoe UI"}
form {display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: center; 
margin: 15px auto; padding: 0 10px;}
fieldset {margin: 0.5rem 0}
fieldset fieldset {display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly; align-items: center;}
legend {font-size: 1.25rem}
button {font: inherit; float: right; cursor: pointer;}
figure {display: inline-flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; 
margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0; padding: 0.5rem;}
.img {display:inline-block; max-width: 5rem}
.highlight {outline: 5px groove cyan;}
```

```html
<form id="gallery">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Area A</legend>
    <fieldset id="A" name="area"></fieldset>
    <button name="add" type="button">ADD</button>
    <button name="bind" type="button">BIND</button>
  </fieldset>
  
  <hr>
  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Area B</legend>
    <fieldset id="B" name="area"></fieldset>
    <button name="add" type="button">ADD</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```